# EF - eliminating nullable fields without changing database

Tags: entity-framework, linq-to-entities, nullreferenceexception, nullable

We have a large legacy transactional-type SqlServer database with hundreds of tables, and most of the fields in these tables have the Allow Null attribute turned on.

We are also using Entity Frameworks and are developing a new C# to access the database.  In the POCO classes generated by EF, the field properties have, of course, the Nullable decorator, which produces nullable data types (e.g., "int ?").

The impact is that if any given field contains null and we don't explicitly check for null before accessing the field, the app will blow up.  Each field also has to be casted for use, or the Value property has to be used.

We could, of course, changes the schema and turn off the Allow Null property, but are getting push-back from the DBA's who want to avoid making any changes.

Is there a way in the EF generator to turn off the Nullable attribute for some or all fields, and coerce the logic to return default values for null fields (e.g., 0 for int, false for bool, etc.) on select statements, and to use default values for inserts/updates?

Comment: Null normally means no value is there. How will you know if there was no value, or that it was populated with a default value of false/0/empty string? Or do you not care about that in this application?

Comment: It would be a thoroughly horrible solution if you had many, many fields that you needed to use, but you could create masking properties of the appropriate type with `get` and `set` logic to guard your nulls.

Comment: EF just represents your data model if your dB fields allow nulls they allow nulls. You will have to handle nulls or change your dB